# Dockerizing a Kotlin Spring Boot app with Gradle in WSL2 won't work

Tags: spring-boot, docker, gradle, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm using WSL 2 and want to dockerize a spring boot kotlin app with gradle (kotlin) and have it all running in Docker so I don't have to install anything locally. But everytime I run a `docker-compose` command I get the same message:

`2024-01-13 13:26:19 Error: Unable to access jarfile ./build/libs/app.jar`

and the spring boot container stops running. Where do I start to look for what's going wrong and how do I proceed?

I tried many different Dockerfiles but this is the most recent one:

```
# Use the official Gradle image with JDK 17 as the base image
FROM gradle:7.4.1-jdk17 AS builder

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN ./gradlew clean build -x test

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["java", "-jar", "./build/libs/app.jar"]
```

docker-compose

```
version: '3'

services:
  mysql:
    image: 'mysql:latest'
    environment:
      - 'MYSQL_DATABASE=twitch-bot'
      - 'MYSQL_PASSWORD=secret'
      - 'MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret'
      - 'MYSQL_HOST=localhost'
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
  spring-boot-kotlin:
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/twitch-bot
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=secret
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Edit:

I ran `docker-compose run yourapp ls build/libs` and was shown `twitch-bot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` and so I changed the `app.jar` in the Dockerfile to `twitch-bot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` and it started outputting other things.

So now the Dockerfile looks like:

```
# Use the official Gradle image with JDK 17 as the base image
FROM gradle:7.4.1-jdk17 AS builder

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN ./gradlew clean build -x test

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["java", "-jar", "./build/libs/twitch-bot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

The `docker build` command outputs:

```
ERROR: "docker buildx build" requires exactly 1 argument.
See 'docker buildx build --help'.

Usage:  docker buildx build [OPTIONS] PATH | URL | -

Start a build
```

I now get errors like this from the spring-boot container:

```
2024-01-13 14:29:53 com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

2024-01-13 14:29:53 2024-01-13T13:29:53.503Z  WARN 1 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata
2024-01-13 14:29:53 
2024-01-13 14:29:53 java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(java.sql.SQLException, String)" because the return value of "org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcIsolationDelegate.sqlExceptionHelper()" is null
```

Comment: Can you provide the output of the `docker build` command?

Comment: If you `docker-compose run yourapp ls build/libs`, is the jar file there?  What's in your Compose file; do you have `volumes:` that hide the image's content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by changing the value of `spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect` to the value `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect`.

So removing the `5` right after `MySQL`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, Change `CMD ["java", "-jar", "./build/libs/app.jar"]` to

```
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
CMD "java -jar ./build/libs/twitch-bot-*.jar"
```

As you noticed the output file is not called `app.jar` but instead as named as gradle does, roughly `{NAME}-{VERSION}.jar`. Changing to [shell format](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#shell-form), while setting the shell to bash enables you to use standard bash-functionalities, like wild-cards to match a changing project version. This helps you maintain a stable, easily-updatable  docker image in the future.

Secondly, (after you updated the question with the java console output),

```
Could not obtain connection to query metadata
```

indicates some connection problems. When using docker-compose together with the `application.properties` you provided:
`spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/twitch-bot` points to `localhost` inside your app container, not your host machine - where the SQL container is listening.
You could change this URL either:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/twitch-bot
```

or

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://host.docker.internal:3306/twitch-bot
```

The first would be preferred, as there is less overhead. The second one can come in handy if you need to communicate with the host machine.

Even better - use environment variables!
Try setting the environment of the your app container to:

```
SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: "jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/twitch-bot"
```

Also, you need to use `docker-compose up` and `docker-compose down`instead of `docker-compose run yourapp ls build/libs` to properly setup all containers and the network.

Comment: Hello, I read everything and applied the changes although sadly I receive this error:

`2024-01-13 18:33:13 /bin/bash: java -jar ./build/libs/twitch-bot-*.jar: No such file or directory`

Comment: mhh. thats strange. try: `CMD "java -jar /app/build/libs/twitch-bot-*.jar"`. However, the second part about networking still stands and needs to be applied nontheless.

Comment: Or: `CMD "/bin/bash -c 'java -jar /app/build/libs/twitch-bot-*.jar'"`

Comment: very same message for both commands sadly... And yes I have been using `docker-compose up` mostly, I just tried that one other command based on one of the comments.